# Creating thousands of files from shell 

Tags: shell, bash

I have thousands of directories, all of them has this format;

```
/var/www/vhosts/[USERNAME].company.com/conf/
```

and i have a file called x.txt, it's content should have

```
[USERNAME] and some static text...
```

so when i do dir /var/www/vhosts/*/conf/ , I am getting all the directories that I need to copy the file under, however, I don't know how to grab that [USERNAME] and put it in that file that i need to copy.

All suggestions welcome. I can only use shell scripting on this environment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/vhosts && for d in */; do
   user=${d%%.*}
   echo "$user blah blah" > "${d}/conf/x.txt"
done
```

... should get you pretty much what you want.

Comment: You should put a slash after the asterisk so only directories are included: `for d in */`

Comment: good point, updated

Comment: Thanks, I saved the world yet again. Would you recommend any good book/url on the subject?

Comment: From Bash to Zsh, by Apress is a good one: http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590593766 .
Also, Classic Shell Scripting from O'Reilly:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0596005954

Answer (score 3):

Dennis and Mike make sure you're quoting ${dir}.  If there are any directories with spaces this could result in some issues.

```
echo "$user and some static text..." > "${dir}/conf/x.txt"
```

For portability's sake I would use "${d%%.*}" for finding the user's name.

Comment: good point on the quotes, and your tip on ${d%%.*} saves over 1000 calls to awk, updated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it:

```
cd /var/www/vhosts &&
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 |
while read -d '' -r dir
do
    user=$(basename "$dir" .company.com)
    echo "$user and some static text..." > "${dir}/conf/x.txt"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I wish I could choose two answers. Would you recommend any good book/url on the subject?

Comment: On Bash scripting? Search ServerFault and StackOverflow. There are questions/answers that'll point the way. One I can recommend is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage

Comment: Thanks Dennis. It's always good to learn from a pro what is worth reading.